# How to get my unconfirmed transaction to confirm. Stuck for 30 days

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations

My coins were sent with low fees by bitclub advantage. Due to this, the transaction is marked on blockchain as 'unconfirmed transaction'. I have tried to get the sender to reverse the transaction or increase fees and they do not respond.
I am not a technical person and only a mere investor. I have seen a lot of explanation and even approached support@viabtc.com for help but nothing has been done yet.
How can I confirm the transaction. I am willing to pay higher fees to unstuck the transaction. 
Question is: Someone explain to a sister like a 5 year old how I can have my coins in my wallet. I need someone to hold my hands and get my hard earned coins.

Thanks